# adminLTE stop working after install livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9, adminlte

i have a site created with laravel 9.16.0 PHP 8.1.5, AdminLTE 3.2 and bootstrap, all was working fine.
i've decide to use Livewire for some stuff.
After installed it and modify the Adminlte.php file  at config folder
i got an error after the user login in and he's redirected to home.blade.php :
message:
InvalidArgumentException: No hint path defined for [adminlte].

git version  shows that only 2 file have been change:
composer.json
composer.lock.
Any idea about this errro?
is there something else that need to bee added /setting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add in composer.json:

```
require": {
"jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "3.*"
}
```

Then run the command:
`composer update`